# progress dialog is not showing the spinner in android version 8.0 but it still works

Tags: android, progressdialog

In my app, the progress dialog should show out when the button is clicked. Now the progress dialog is shown but without spinner or the loading bar(sorry I'm not sure what it's call)

This is how my progress dialog looks like in android 8.0 real device

[image: This is how my progress dialog looks like in android 8.0 real device]

This is how my progress dialog looks like in android 5.0

[image]

```
  private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

     @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);
    }

         public void loginUser(View v) {
            final String Email = emailText.getText().toString();
            final String password = passwordText.getText().toString();

            progressDialog.setMessage("Logging in....");
            progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            progressDialog.show();

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(Email)) {
                emailText.setError("Email is required");
            }
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
                passwordText.setError("password is required");
            }
            if ((!TextUtils.isEmpty(Email)) && (!TextUtils.isEmpty(password))) {
                mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(Email, password)
                        .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    Toasty.error(getApplicationContext(), "Login Failed",
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, true).show();
                                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                                } else {
      Toasty.success(getApplicationContext(), "Login Success",
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, true).show();
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, Admins.class);
                                    intent.putExtra("Email", emailText.getText().toString());
                                    startActivity(intent);
                  }
           }
     }
```

Can anyone help me to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ProgressDialog

is deprecated from SDK 26. You should use

> ProgressBar

**Usage:**

In your layout add the view:

```
<ProgressBar
   android:id="@+id/progressBar"
   style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/parent"
   app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/parent"
   app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
   android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
   android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
   android:indeterminate="true"
   android:max="100"
   android:visibility="gone"/>
```

Declare your `progressBar` in your activity

```
ProgressBar progressBar;
```

In `onCreate` get the view

```
progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
```

When you need to show the progressBar:

```
progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

When you need it to be gone:

```
progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

For more details take a look into [ProgressBar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html) docs

It could be helpful to disable user interaction while `ProgressBar` is up.

**EDIT**

**Disabling interaction**

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
```

**Reenabling interaction:**

```
getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
```

**EDIT 2**

You don't need to copy `ProgressDialog` visual as per Material Design patterns ([Progress Indicators](https://material.io/design/components/progress-indicators.html#)).

**EDIT 3**

Here is an example for what I said to you in comments. It is a layout for a ProgressBar inside a View

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:background="#EFEFEF">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Things to do"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"/>

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:indeterminate="true"
            android:max="100"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:layout_below="@+id/title"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Please wait we are doing things..."
            android:layout_below="@+id/title"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/progressBar"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/progressBar"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

It'll produce something like this:
[image: How it looks]

You can set elevation for API 21 or higher:

```
android:elevation="10dp"
```

As you asked in comments, this is just an example, **not a recommendation**. It's not the most beautiful layout you'll see in life, but it will give you a north.

Comment: do u know how to set title and setOutsideclickable false?

Comment: @overflowstack `ProgressBar` itself does not have a setTitle or setText. To disable click, see my edit.

Comment: so what should i use to display something like progress dialog?

Comment: @overflowstack You should create a `View` and then add `Textviews` for title and text. Add progress inside this View.

Comment: @overflowstack take a look at my edit. If it answer your question, mark it as solved.